# How to set a user's default view from JavaScript in Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics

I'd like to set a users default view for a table depending on their business unit.

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can set the default view like this:

```
async function setDefaultView(viewId: string) {
  if(!viewId.startsWith('{') || !viewId.endsWith('}')) {
    throw new Error('Your viewId should probably start and end with curly braces like this: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}');
  }

  const userId = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId.slice(1, -1); // Remove the curly braces from the user id, because ODATA doesn't want them
  await fetch(
    `${window.location.origin}/api/data/v9.0/usersettingscollection(${userId})`,
    {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        personalizationsettings: `
          <DefaultGridViews>
            <DefaultGridView>
              <EntityTypeCode>1024</EntityTypeCode>
              <ChildEntityName></ChildEntityName>
              <QueueId></QueueId>
              <ViewId>${viewId}</ViewId>
              <ViewType>1039</ViewType>
            </DefaultGridView>
          </DefaultGridViews>
        `.replaceAll(/\s/g, '')
      })
    }
  );
}
```

> **Note**: This shouldn't overwrite the personalization settings for other tables. When using patch, dynamics is smart enough to merge the personalizationsettings for you.